# When to use the __gc keyword on managed C++ classes?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compilation, header, c++-cli

I have a C++ project that I've successfully wrapped with .NET classes using C++/CLI. I'm defining the wrapper classes in managed C++. Do I need to mark the classes as `__gc` in order for the classes to be garbage collected? Or will the .NET framework automatically GC the classes since they are managed classes?

This is how its currently declared

```
public ref class Player {
```

Do I need something like this?

```
__gc class Player { .. }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The keyword `__gc` was used in the previous version (IIRC, till VS2003). Then the new context-specific keywords (like `ref class`, `value struct`) were added. Newer compilers (VS2005+) would understand and suggest to use newer keywords. Context keyword `ref class` is enough to state that this class is a managed class. Managed classes can only be allocated using `gcnew` keyword. The compiler will raise an error of `new` is used for managed-classes. For VC++ (`/clr`), stack-semantics are also available.

That means the following is also valid:

```
public ref class SomeClass{};

void foo()
{
    SomeClass cls; // On stack!    
}
```

Answer (score 4):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa712825%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

> The keyword __gc on a class or struct indicates that it is
>   garbage-collected, and its lifetime is managed by the common language
>   runtime. No explicit calls to delete are required in the user program.

But still, if you allocate memory inside of the class, you need to release it inside of finalizer with delete or free, depending on allocation type

```
public ref class PAWrapper
{
private:
    PAPor *pap;

public:

    PAWrapper()
    {
        pap = new PAPor();
    }

    ~PAWrapper(){this->!PAWrapper();}

    !PAWrapper()
    {
        delete pap;
        pap = NULL;
    }
}
```

So no, you do NOT need `__gc`, but you should define finalizer ( !PAWrapper() ) to avoid memory leaks. The finalizer will be called by GC automatically

Comment: What kind of textbook answer is this? Do I need the __gc keyword on my managed C++ class or not?

Comment: @Geotarget no, you do NOT need it, but you should define finalizer !PAWrapper() to avoid memory leaks